# Retaining institutional knowledge of a complex infrastructure (checkpoint, juniper, etc)

Tags: network, firewalls

In the next month my functions will be expanded to include IT security (firewalls, VPN, PKI) in a big complex infrastructure. Can I ask you for advice on how-to be well prepared for it?  What sorts of tools and checklists should I use when transferring institutional knowledge from colleagues who have decided to leave the company?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want at a minimum:

1.) logical infrastructure diagrams

2.) physical infrastructure diagrams

3.) usernames/passwords at the admin (enabled) level

4.) peer router lists

5.) trusted user lists

From this point you can audit configuration settings and start baselining the current network activity. Where you go from there is up to you.

Comment: You should also ask for details of any known risks that have been accepted by the teams / organisation. There may be activities that go against company policy that have been "accepted" but will become your issue. So being aware would be a positive.

Comment: great, very valuble

Answer (score 3):

Some great information already provided, I would also add:

1. In addition to @iivel's answer you
   will also want documentation on
   management of the environments,
   especially PKI. There should be
   ceremony documents, practice
   statements, support plan info, etc.
2. Any documentation detailing patch 
   cycles and management plans would be 
   useful.
3. Depending on the maturity of your 
   organisation and predecessors (they
   are being replaced after all ;)), the
   concept of 'risks' may not be common.
   Instead it may be worthwhile asking
   your predecessor for any known 
   *problems*, with or without an existing remediation plan.
4. Handover of any auditing requirements, their renewal timeframes, and compliance objectives. Included would be any past audits and their findings.
5. Credentials for relevant management tools, such as network/firewall monitoring and auditing.